# Condense List[Dict[key, list]] so that duplicated keys have their lists converted to list of lists for each unique key

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, set

Apologies if the title is confusing. The examples may make it more clear. I have a List[Dict[str, list]] that is formatted such that a list of values are associated with the key ID (example data):

> [{'values': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'ID':
> 'AAA'}, {'values': ['5', '6', '7',
> '8'], 'ID': 'AAA'}, {'values': ['9',
> '10', '11', '12'], 'ID': 'BBB'},
> {'values': ['13', '14', '15', '16'], 'ID':
> 'BBB'}, {'values': ['17', '18', '19',
> '20'], 'ID': 'CCC'}, {'values': ['21',
> '22', '23', '24'], 'ID': 'CCC'}]

I would like to condense this so that ID becomes unique, and if there are multiples Lists of values for one ID, they are combined into a List of List, such that the previous example becomes:

> [{'values': [['1', '2', '3', '4'],['5', '6', '7', '8']], 'ID': 'AAA'},
> {'values': [['9', '10', '11', '12'],['13', '14', '15', '16']], 'ID': 'BBB'},
> {'values': [['17', '18', '19', '20'],['21', '22', '23', '24']], 'ID': 'CCC'}]

I am having significant difficulty accomplishing this. My first idea was to extract all of the ID's and put them into a separate Set so they are unique, but then I was lost from there on how to proceed with changing the structure so the List actually becomes a List of Lists. I was wondering if there was any intuitive Python solution for this as my searches returned no results.

As a side note, I would also prefer if 'values' and 'ID' were swapped so the ID comes first, but this doesn't actually matter, it would just make it easier to look at in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary dictionary where keys are your `ID` keys and values are lists of lists. Then convert this dictionary to list of dictionaries:

```
from pprint import pprint

lst = [
    {"values": ["1", "2", "3", "4"], "ID": "AAA"},
    {"values": ["5", "6", "7", "8"], "ID": "AAA"},
    {"values": ["9", "10", "11", "12"], "ID": "BBB"},
    {"values": ["13", "14", "15", "16"], "ID": "BBB"},
    {"values": ["17", "18", "19", "20"], "ID": "CCC"},
    {"values": ["21", "22", "23", "24"], "ID": "CCC"},
]

out = {}
for item in lst:
    out.setdefault(item["ID"], []).append(item["values"])

out = [{"ID": k, "values": v} for k, v in out.items()]

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'ID': 'AAA', 'values': [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8']]},
 {'ID': 'BBB', 'values': [['9', '10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', '16']]},
 {'ID': 'CCC', 'values': [['17', '18', '19', '20'], ['21', '22', '23', '24']]}]
```

Comment: This works perfectly except for the part for when the keys and values were swapped. I couldn't replicate how you were able to get the ID to come first even after fiddling with the "out =" line. Regardless, thank you very much for this solution.